# how to change color of Circle in every second

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, shapes

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;      // Graphics, Shape
import java.awt.geom.*; //Graphics2D
/*
<applet code = Oval1.class height=300 width=300 >
</applet>
*/
public class Oval1 extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Shape circle;
    Color c;
    public void init() {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(90,100, 90, 90);
        repaint();
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println(1);
                c = Color.cyan;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(2);
                c = Color.gray;
                repaint();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        d.setColor(c);
        d.fill(circle);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an applet that has a filled circle in middle of the applet & changing the color of circle in every second, means I want to show the circle like it's blinking.

I want to change color of circle in every second.

For this I use Shape class & Thread, but it's still not working.

I already try by using  `paint(g)` by overriding update method..

This will not also effect

Comment: Do you get the System.out.println output?

Comment: yes, in console I got both println statement in every second...

Comment: The c changes its color but you do not see it. Add Thread.sleep(1000); to the end of the while block after repaint(); and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Thread.sleep(1000) after second repaint().

```
        while(true) {

            System.out.println(1);
            c = Color.cyan;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(2);
            c = Color.gray;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Java Timer in place of Thread.sleep(). For example using of Timer, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html. Thread.sleep() block paint method of applet.

Comment: I have to use Thread because , It's my school assignment, definition provided by my professor...

Comment: Can you give done my example with using Timer class because I don't know use of Timer class of swing ??

Comment: You can look that http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Java_applets or http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/other/10time/20timer.html

Answer (score 1):

try out this..

Just need to put **Thread.sleep(1000);** after second repaint(), currently after second repaint immediately first repaint call so it over paint on second **repaint();**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;      // Graphics, Shape
import java.awt.geom.*; //Graphics2D
/*
<applet code = Oval1.class height=300 width=300 >
</applet>
*/
public class Oval1 extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Shape circle;
    Color c;
    public void init() {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(90,100, 90, 90);
        repaint();
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println(1);
                c = Color.cyan;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(2);
                c = Color.gray;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        d.setColor(c);
        d.fill(circle);
    }
}
```